GitKraken issue when checkout with submodule
I have a problem when I checkout from one branch to another in a repo containing git submodules.
For example:
parent-repo (branch master)
.
├── test.txt
└── README.md

parent-repo (branch develop)
.
├── .gitmodules
├── test.txt
├── README.md
└── child-repo
    └── README.md

When I run, from develop, git checkout master from the shell, VSCode or other tools (like SourceTre), I don't have any problem.
But when I do it from GitKraken, the contents of moduleA are copied to branch master. There is no .gitmodules file created, but the entire content is copied.

To summarize, if branch A contains more submodules than branch B, the content of all submodules present in branch A is copied to branch B.

Does anyone know what the problem is? And how to fix it?
I've tried to deinit submodules, and it seems that when submodules are not initialized, this problem disappears!

Update: Issue resolved
The bug has been fixed in the version 10.4.0 GitKraken Desktop Release Note
